# FacebookAds: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I am using [Facebook Audience Network](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/android/add-sdk) for monetize the app, but recently I got massive issue in crashlytics after upgraded targetSdkVersion to 31, i use this dependency

```
implementation ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.5.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
```

and i initialized my apps with this snippet code in `onCreate` Application class

```
private fun defaultProcessInitialization(app: NewsApplication?) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectAll()
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .build())
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectAll()
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .build())
        }
        // Let Audience Network SDK know that you want to use Multiprocess Support
        AdSettings.setMultiprocessSupportMode(
                AdSettings.MultiprocessSupportMode.MULTIPROCESS_SUPPORT_MODE_ON)

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            AdSettings.addTestDevice("xxxxx")
        }

        AudienceNetworkAds
                .buildInitSettings(app)
                .withInitListener(app)
                .initialize()
    }
```

But the problem only appears in Android S

this is log report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mobile.android.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
       at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:465)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:451)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:415)
       at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.FF.E(FF.java:25701)
       at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Fn.C(Fn.java:26419)
       at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Fl.FC(Fl.java:26298)
       at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Fl.PC(Fl.java:26369)
       at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8E.C(8E.java:18158)
       at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8E.getBidderToken(8E.java:18169)
       at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.FP.run(FP.java:25949)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Please someone help me

Answer (score 2):

`com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.5.0` is from August 2019. It is far behind the now-current 6.8.0 version. And, in particular, August 2019 is well before Android 12 shipped.

Eventually, you will need to upgrade to the latest version, then hope that Facebook added the flag to the `PendingIntent`.

Alternatively, you could drop your `targetSdkVersion` back to 30 for a while.

Comment: I have tried to update dependency to be `implementation ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.8.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }` but all class become unresolved (error build), there is no update configuration in documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/android/initialize-sdk, they just encourage use manual installation but that encounter new issue

Comment: @NandaZ: Sorry, but I cannot help with that, as I do not know the details of that particular library and the API that it exposes.

Comment: no problem, i only notice that 6.8.0 only for manual installation. But that libs produce ANR problem (although build is successfully). It seems unstable yet

Comment: @NandaZ: You could try [6.6.0 or 6.7.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/audience-network-sdk), as they may still be recent enough to have a `PendingIntent` fix.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i finally can read this dependency. I will try to implement this lib first and vote this answer after crash solved